# How to use coverage.py to display line numbers of function defintions?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I want to measure the functional coverage of python programs. Reporting the line numbers of the function def lines. Can this be done using Ned Batchelder's Coverage.py? There's branch coverage which shows the line numbers of branch statements.

Coverage.py version 5.1 is used.

In the [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/faq.html) there's this FAQ:

> Q: Why do the bodies of functions (or classes) show as executed, but the def lines do not?
>
> This happens because coverage.py is started after the functions are
>   defined. The definition lines are executed without coverage
>   measurement, then coverage.py is started, then the function is called.
>   This means the body is measured, but the definition of the function
>   itself is not.
>
> To fix this, start coverage.py earlier. If you use the command line to
>   run your program with coverage.py, then your entire program will be
>   monitored. If you are using the API, you need to call coverage.start()
>   before importing the modules that define your functions.

I tried to utilize the def lines not being included, in a reverse manner for my own goal.

```
import coverage

cov = coverage.coverage()
srcfnDict = {"key1":["a"], "key2":["a", "b", "c"], "key3":["a", "b"]}

def display(srcfnDict):
    for src, fns in srcfnDict.items():
        for i in fns:
            print(src, " ", i)

def add():
    a = 5 + 10
    return a

cov.start()
display(srcfnDict)
add()

cov.stop()
cov.save()
```

And this is the report generated from the command line:
[image: Report generated test.py from the command line]

This includes only the function bodies. Is there any way I can include only the function definitions in the coverage report?

Comment: You shouldn't need the coverage API.  Just use "coverage run yourprogram.py" on the command line.

Comment: Hi @NedBatchelder! My project's requirement is to output the names of functions aka def lines that get executed in the python scripts.

Comment: When using the API, coverage will only be measured for code in functions called after the API starts.  Your def lines have already been executed before you start coverage.